# Name of a variable as string, how to get value?

Tags: javascript

A javascript newbie question:

Let's say, there is a variable defined as follows:

```
var var1 = "Something"
```

On the other hand, I generate such strings (simplified):

```
var nmbr = "1"
var varname = "var" + nmbr
```

Now I have to get the value of a variable with such a name (varname as string).

```
document.write([???varname???])
```

should write 'Something'.

How to do this?

Comment: you can get it from the current scope, i.e. `this[varname]` or `window[varname]`

Comment: You should probably be using an array.

Comment: @PanamaProphet— *this* is not the "current scope", it may not even be an object. You can't reference execution records (i.e. the "current scope"), it's not allowed by the specification.

Comment: @Panama Prophet -- Thank you!!! `this[varname]` works fine for me!

Comment: @RobG yes, thanks for correction, you are right. what i mean was a context, not scope

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(variable_name);
```

will print the variable in the console.